# The determinant of sum of squares of a special family of real $2\times2$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A_0, A_1, \ldots, A_n \in M_2(\mathbb R)$ (with $n\ge 2$) be nonzero matrices with the following properties:
$$
\begin{cases}
A_0 \neq aI_2&\forall a\in\mathbb R,\\
A_0A_k=A_kA_0&\forall k \in \{1,2,...,n\}.
\end{cases}
$$
Prove that

a) $\det(\sum_{k=1}^n A_k^2 )\ge 0$,

b) if $\det(\sum_{k=1}^n A_k^2)=0$ and $A_2\neq aA_1$ for every $a\in\mathbb R$, then $\sum_{k=1}^nA_k^2=0$.

I have tried to show that $\det(\sum_{k=1}^n A_k^2 )\ge 0$ is a square but failed. Please help!

Comment: Commuting matrices share eigenvectors. See if you can then prove that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n A_k^2$'s eigenvalues are nonnegative.

Comment: @CarlHeckman Would you please elaborate? Commuting matrices share *at least one* eigenvector, but in general they are not necessarily simultaneously Jordanisable. The fact that the matrices are real and $2\times2$ seem to play an important role here.

Comment: @ user1551: That's why what I said was a comment (a suggestion, really) and not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Hints.*

- If $A_0$ is not a scalar multiple of the identity, show that it is either (i) a diagonalisable matrix with two distinct real eigenvalues, (ii) a scalar multiple of a rotation matrix with a conjugate pair of non-real eigenvalues, or (iii) similar to a $2\times2$ Jordan block.
- In each of the above three cases, what matrices commute with $A_0$?